# How to use spring web services dynamic WSDL generation in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-boot

I followed [Spring Web Services Getting Started tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/#tutorial) and I've put together a sample web app that dynamically generates the WSDL at `/ws/holiday.wsdl` and the endpoint serves requests at `/ws/holidayService`, so far so good.

Now I am turning that webapp to a Spring Boot app: I've added the necessary `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies, created a `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in a package above the one with the endpoint and the endpoint implementation still replies to the requests.

But I can no longer get the generated WSDL out of the existing XSD.

This is `application.properties` (I tried putting the XSD in more than one place):

```
server.port = 8090
spring.webservices.wsdl-locations=classpath:/../;classpath:/wsdl
spring.webservices.path=/ws
```

This is the `Run as -> Spring Boot App` log (I'm in Eclipse):

```
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@13df2a8c: startup date [Mon Sep 24 14:40:44 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$22b02c9a] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
.w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.6.3].
o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.0.2m  2 Nov 2017]
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2093 ms
o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/ws/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@13df2a8c: startup date [Mon Sep 24 14:40:44 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
```

Spring Boot [documentation on Web Service](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-webservices) says:

> Spring Boot provides Web Services auto-configuration so that all you must do is define your Endpoints.
>
> The Spring Web Services features can be easily accessed with the spring-boot-starter-webservices module.
>
> SimpleWsdl11Definition and SimpleXsdSchema beans can be automatically created for your WSDLs and XSDs respectively. To do so, configure their location, as shown in the following example:
>
> `spring.webservices.wsdl-locations=classpath:/wsdl`

As I'm new to Boot, it's unclear to me whether WSDL dynamic generation is supported (and I'm just missing the right configuration) or not at all.

Comment: Have you had a look at this example here: https://www.javainuse.com/spring/springbootsoapwebservice

Comment: @SimonMartinelli If I'm not mistaking, that page makes use of an explicit WSDL; however, I think I found a solution based on [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/), I made the following changes:

#### 1. `web.xml`

Removed the `web.xml` file in favor of adding:

```
spring.webservices.servlet.init.transformWsdlLocations=true
spring.webservices.path=/ws
```

to the `application.properties` file.

#### 2. `spring-ws-servlet.xml`

Removed the `spring-ws-servlet.xml` configuration file and added:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "holiday")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema schema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("HumanResource");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/holidayService/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

}
```

I placed this class beside the `@SpringBootApplication`–annotated class so it will be discovered without further configuration — the values set are the same as those in the Spring servlet configuration file.

#### 3. `hr.xsd`

Moved the `hr.xsd` schema file to `src/main/resources/ws` and added

```
spring.webservices.wsdl-locations=classpath:/ws/
```

to the `application.properties` file.

---

## UPDATE

It is possible to output several separate WSDL files by corresponding different schemas too.

Given `holiday-spring-schema.xsd` and `holiday-winter-schema.xsd` schema files, the corresponding WSDLs `holiday-spring.wsdl` and `holiday-winter.wsdl` can be generated with the following:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "holiday-spring")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11DefinitionOne(@Qualifier("holiday-spring-schema") XsdSchema schema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("HumanResource");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/holidaySpringService/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean(name = "holiday-winter")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11DefinitionTwo(@Qualifier("holiday-winter-schema") XsdSchema schema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("HumanResource");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/holidayWinterService/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://mycompany.com/hr/definitions");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

}
```