# What endpoint i can use to genarete wsdl with spring-boot soap web service

Tags: java, spring-boot, wsdl

I'm following this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ to learn about spring-boot. My point is I always managed the wsdl with endpoint?wsdl like this sample http://server/PortName?wsdl. But with spring-boot i don't get how to do this. I use the wsimport command to import and generate all classes needed to consume the web services. On spring-boot it's possible?

Comment: Where exactly is the problem. In the missing `?` in the published wsdl? In springboot, you get a `.` instead. I'm not sure it can be easily changed, but didn't have any issues when using it for generating clients.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use spring web services dynamic WSDL generation in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479912/how-to-use-spring-web-services-dynamic-wsdl-generation-in-spring-boot)

Comment: when i use another implementations i generate the wsdl i use the endpoint with final string "?wsdl". But i'm not knowing how show descriptor in browser. For the code on github i running and tried access the http://localhost:8080/ws/countries?wsdl to see the wsdl but are showing error.